# Create Node REST API that calls remote REST API and returns results

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, bluebird

I have a local REST API though I'm only really dealing with POST's.

```
mysite/api/ -> http://remoteSite.com/api/
```

so when my front end hits my endpoint with params the server would then post those to the remote server (3rd party API) and return the results to the original POST.

I've tried looking at Koa, Express, Axios, Bluebird but I can't seem to find a reasonable way to do it or a decent search term to find examples.

Comment: What are you using for your local API? Are you writing the remote API or calling 3rd party endpoints? Either way, you can use Superagent (https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) to communicate between your local and the remote.

Comment: It is a 3rd party API. I haven't chosen as I assumed it would use a piece of middleware and that would be specific to my choice, I'll search for superagent examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a **proxy**.

---

If you have to use NodeJS, you could for example look into [the node-http-proxy library](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy):

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000'}).listen(8000); 

//
// Create your target server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#setup-a-basic-stand-alone-proxy-server)

Here, localhost port 8000 acts as a proxy for localhost port 9000. You want to set this up to point to a remote server instead.

---

You could also look into the [Apache web server](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) for alternative ways to set up a proxy, potentially with less effort and more stability.

Comment: I was going to stick with doing it in node as I'm only really fluent in Javascript, I was unsure if doing it via proxy was ok. Previously I've done this from the frontend but wanted to learn more backend methods and servers and felt this would be good as companies can have similar scenarios where they don't want to expose internal api's

Comment: This is a common use case for proxies, and because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), it can't even be implemented in the front end in many cases. You should be good with this approach.

Comment: ah now I remember, you can have a lot of cors issues. I meant I would hit the 3rd party API direct from the frontend. ie things like twitter api and other testing apis. In the example you gave could I split the API to specific endpoints? this is probably where a framework would help?

Comment: If you are already using express, you could look into [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware), which is a wrapper around node-http-proxy and makes it very simple to map different endpoints to separate remote servers.

Comment: ahhh think that is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: one last thing what if I wanted to filter/adjust the response prior to sending back to front end would that be achievable when doing a proxy or will the proxy purely act as a go between so to speak?

Comment: Not simple, but possible: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#modify-a-response-from-a-proxied-server